# Optimize and shorten union query

Tags: php, mysql

Below is my query to get a bulk of attributes of some objects. Are there anyway to optimize and shorten it?

```
SELECT object_id, value, name FROM attr_text WHERE object_id IN ('43', '42', '41', '40', '39') 
UNION 
SELECT object_id, value, name FROM attr_varchar WHERE object_id IN ('43', '42', '41', '40', '39') 
UNION
SELECT object_id, value, name FROM attr_int WHERE object_id IN ('43', '42', '41', '40', '39') 
UNION
SELECT object_id, value, name FROM attr_decimal WHERE object_id IN ('43', '42', '41', '40', '39') 
UNION
SELECT object_id, value, name FROM attr_datetime WHERE object_id IN ('43', '42', '41', '40', '39')
```

Results:

```
43   red    color1
43   blue   color2
43   small  size
42   black  color1
42   big    size
```

Comment: Lists of named attributes by data-types keyed by an identifier... sounds like a job for an SQL table... oh wait.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most obvious improvement you could make is to use a sensible schema.

Assuming that's not an option, one thing I would suggest is changing `UNION` to `UNION ALL` as you probably don't have have multiple attributes with the same name and value. The `UNION [DISTINCT]` just performs unnecessary comparisons. In any case you aren't handling attributes with the same name and *different* values in your current query.

Comment: Hi, can you explain more about sensible schema. Sorry but english is my L2. Btw, union all may be faster because it does not check duplicated content. Thank you.

Comment: @StoneHeart: I don't think I can give you a recommendation of how your schema should be without knowing more about your application, but I can tell you that you should know that what you are doing is very similar to EAV, and I suggest you read about that. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model And I'd suggest that you consider whether a) EAV is a suitable approach for your application and b) Whether your variation on EAV offers any benefits over the standard EAV approach.

Answer (score 1):

I too would suggest that the best improvement you could make is to use a sane schema.  To elaborate, it'll greatly simplify your SQL and improve performance if you can define a discrete list of columns for your objects, like so:

```
create table [Object] (
    [object_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [color1] [varchar](255) null,
    [color2] [varchar](255) null,
    [size] [varchar](255) null
    ... any other properties.... 
)

alter table Object
add constraint PK_object_id
primary key clustered (
    object_id
)
```

Then, you can just select all your objects using a simple select:

```
select * from object where object_id in ( '43', '42', '41', '40', '39' )
```